# How to use $transaction API in this scenario?

Tags: prisma, prisma2, prisma-transaction

```
const a = prisma.user.create()
throw new Error() // some error happened
const b = prisma.user.create()
prisma.$transaction([a, b])
```

Since an error happened, `prisma.$transaction` was never called, so `a` inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

`a` will never be inserted into the database as the `prisma.user.create()` command will only be called inside `prisma.$transaction` so you do not need to check for that.

Comment: But in reality, ```a``` dose insert into database.

Comment: That's not possible, Prisma's API is lazy by default so no insert will happen before the transaction. I can send you an example as well if possible.

Comment: If i just use ```create()``` with no ```await``` and open the ```debug``` option of prisma, the console shows ```BEGIN; INSERT...; COMMIT;```, so it just auto commit my insert, is there an option can stop auto commit i don't know?  @Ryan

Comment: Maybe later i can create a small repo, i'll keep in touch. very much thinks. @Ryan

Comment: Yes please do at [this link](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/new) so that I can reproduce :)

Comment: Hi @Ryan, [look here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/6355)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
const [a, b] = await prisma.$transaction([prisma.user.create(), prisma.user.create()])
```